# Как указать размер окна обозревателя?

Tags: javascript, html, css, браузер

Как указать размер окна обозревателя? Возможно через `JavaScript` или `CSS`. Только, чтобы не новое окно открывалось с нужным параметром размера (200х500пкс), а чтобы, например, страница заранее была нужного размера, и  можно было бы с гугл нажать на ссылку и окно открылось бы заданного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменять параметры window.outerWidth/window.outerHeight, а также можно использовать:

```
 window.resizeTo(x, y);//Изменяет размеры окна к конкретным значениям

 window.resizeBy(x, y);//Изменяет размеры окна на конкретные значения
```